# is fastai structured module stille there

Tags: google-colaboratory

```
from fastai.imports import *
from fastai.structured import *

from pandas_summary import DataFrameSummary
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, RandomForestClassifier
from IPython.display import display

from sklearn import metrics
```

Comment: can you state what's your question? It's not very clear and I see only code

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are asking whether the fastai.structured module is still in fastai v1?

If you're following the fastai machine learning courses, then no. They were based on fastai v0.7.0.

You have to follow [these](https://forums.fast.ai/t/wiki-thread-lesson-1/6825) instructions for installing fastai to work through the fast.ai machine learning courses.